# How can a big number fit precisely into `double` with 32-bit GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point, compiler-bug

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    long long x = 123456789123456789;
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    auto y = static_cast<double>(x);  // (1)
    std::cout << static_cast<long long>(y) << "\n";  // (2)
    std::cout << y << "\n";
    std::cout << (x == static_cast<long long>(y)) << "\n";  // (3)
    std::cout << static_cast<long long>(static_cast<double>(x)) << "\n";  // (4)
    std::cout << (x == static_cast<long long>(static_cast<double>(x))) << "\n";  // (5)
}
```

When compiled with 32-bit GCC on Linux (`g++ -m32 a.cpp`), [it prints as follows](https://godbolt.org/z/MWxa3c4Wd):

```
123456789123456784
123456789123456784.000000
0
123456789123456789
1
```

Note that result of converting `long long` to `double` and then back to `long long` is different depending on how it was done. If I do it via a separate variable `double y` (lines `(1)` and `(2)`), the result ends with 4. But if I do everything in one expression (line `(4)`), the result ends with 9 just as the original value.

This is quite inconvenient: there exists no `double` that results in `123456789123456789` when converted to `long long`, and the check in line `(3)` confirms that. However, the check in the line `(5)` passes as if there is one. Is it a bug in GCC or my program?

This behavior started in GCC 9 according to Godbolt link above, GCC 8 works fine. Even funnier, if I add `-O2`, all expressions are optimized away during compilation and the output is:

```
123456789123456784
123456789123456784.000000
0
123456789123456784
0
```

And if I read `x` from `std::cin` and keep `-O2`, the intermediate variable ends in `4`, but after conversion to `long long` a wild `9` appears.

```
123456789123456789
123456789123456784.000000
1
123456789123456789
1
```

I believe there is no undefined behavior in the program above:

- Conversion from an integer type to a floating-point type is kind of defined: it results in a rounded floating-point value. So either `123456789123456784` or `123456789123456790`.
- Both of these values fit into `long long`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GCC does document this non-standard behavior in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html.

When no `-std=c++XX` option is given (i.e. if a default `-std=gnu++XX` is used), then `-fexcess-precision` is set to `fast`.

The effect of this is that, in violation of the C and C++ standards, GCC assumes that operations can always be carried out in higher precision than the types permit and whether this will happen in any given instance is unspecified.

The C and C++ standards however require casts and assignment to round to a value representable in the actual target type. Therefore the result of your checks is not permitted to be `1` as you describe. (However, for other, i.e. arithmetic, operations in a single expression the standards *do* explicitly permit operation in higher precision.)

You get the standard-conforming behavior with `-fexcess-precision=standard` which is automatically enabled with a `-std=c++XX` option. However, for C++, it has been implemented only since GCC 13.

Similarly GCC defaults to `-ffp-contract=fast`, which is also non-conforming and permits GCC to contract floating point operations across statements, i.e. to assume infinite precision intermediate results, while the standards again don't permit this across statements, casts or assignment. The standard-conforming option is `-ffp-contract=on` (or `-ffp-contract=off` to completely disable it).

(This however doesn't mean that there aren't still bugs that make the behavior non-conforming as discussed in the bug reports linked in the other answer.)

Comment: Fun fact: GCC's `-ffp-contract=on` is the same as `off`; presumably the internals don't support tracking whether a multiply and add were part of the same expression or not, so the only way to avoid contracting across statements is to not contract at all. https://godbolt.org/z/dqKqvd8f8 shows GCC vs. clang: clang does fully support `on`.

Answer (score 17):

This seems like another instance of the infamous [GCC (non-)bug 323](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323). One might argue it's closer to e.g. [bug 85957](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85957) as the issue happens with integers and without any computations with floating-point numbers.

However, the underlying issue is probably the same: [GCC uses `long double` for computations](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath#line-82) under the hood in 32-bit mode because that's what 8086's FPU (8087) used back in the old days. Looking [at the disassembly](https://godbolt.org/z/18fPY85b6):

```x86asm
; auto y = static_cast<double>(x);  // (1)
    ; Load `x` from address `ebp-16` into `ST(0)`, the 80-bit top of the FPU's stack:
    fild    QWORD PTR [ebp-16]
    ; Load the top of the stack into `y` at `ebp-24`, truncated from 80 bits to 64 bits
    fstp    QWORD PTR [ebp-24]
; std::cout << static_cast<long long>(y) << "\n";  // (2)
    ; Load `y` from `ebp-24` into `ST(0)`, that's 64 bits value already
    fld     QWORD PTR [ebp-24]
    ...
; std::cout << static_cast<long long>(static_cast<double>(x)) << "\n";  // (4)
    ; Load `x` from address `ebp-16` into `ST(0)`, the 80-bit top of the FPU's stack:
    fild    QWORD PTR [ebp-16]
    ; Work with `ST(0)` directly, that's 80-bit
    ...
```

So, line `(1)` actually stores the `double` into a memory location and truncates it to 64 bits, line `(2)` later takes these 64 bits from the memory. But line `(4)` works directly with 80-bit registers and `123456789123456789` fits into 80-bit IEEE extended double precision number precisely. Hence, no rounding, and after a bit of code we have this exact value back in `long long`.

Surprisingly, even adding `-msse -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -march=skylake` options do not change the outcome on the most recent GCC 13.2.  I thought "using SSE instructions instead of x87" (as I believe is the default with `g++ -m64`) would change something, but it's not.

If truncating to 64 bits is important, I'd suggest going through an intermediate `volatile double y` variable:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    long long x;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    volatile auto y = static_cast<double>(x);  // (1)
    std::cout << static_cast<long long>(y) << "\n";  // (2)
    std::cout << y << "\n";
    std::cout << (x == static_cast<long long>(y)) << "\n";  // (3)
    std::cout << static_cast<long long>(static_cast<double>(x)) << "\n";  // (4)
    std::cout << (x == static_cast<long long>(static_cast<double>(x))) << "\n";  // (5)
}
```

when compiled with `g++ -m32` and given `123456789123456789` as the input [it prints](https://godbolt.org/z/8T4d5Tod4):

```
123456789123456784
123456789123456784.000000
0
123456789123456789
1
```

`volatile` forces GCC to actually store and load `double` into memory, forcing rounding 80-bit value to 64 bits. Not sure how documented that is. A program-wide documented option would be `-ffloat-store`.

Comment: Related: see discussion in comments on [Homemade 'fabs' function in C and x86 Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/135980679) - the interesting part of the OP's results was that `-189.55f` after promotion to `double` had more precision than a `float` could have had, as if it had been parsed as `189.55`.  (The inline asm part of the question was unrelated.)  Interestingly in that case, `-fexcess-precision=fast` gave the result we expected.  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108742 / https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=110476 are most relevant.